# JAVA Android , acces to a file with getRessourceAsStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

i would like to handle a a properties file in my android app. The Properties-File is in the main-Folder, in the folder with the other jar-files. I know, that´s not best.

Code:

```
InputStream propStream=MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
         Log.d("propStreamOutput",propStream.toString());
                File data = new File(propStream.toString());


                Reader reader;
                try {
                    reader = new FileReader(data);
                     dataProp = new Properties();
                     dataProp.load( reader );
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                  catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

so, the log at line 2 says: 
libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl$JarURLConnectionInputStream@421302e8

in this form logcat calls a System.err :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException/libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl$JarURLConnectionInputStream@42097218: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

but when I comment like this:

```
        InputStream propStream=MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
         Log.d("propStreamOutput",propStream.toString());
                File data = new File(propStream.toString());


//                  Reader reader;
//                  try {
//                      reader = new FileReader(data);
//                       dataProp = new Properties();
//                       dataProp.load( reader );
//                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                      e.printStackTrace();
//                  }
//                  
//                    catch (IOException e) {
//                              // TODO Auto-generated  catch block
//                              e.printStackTrace();
//                          }
```

then there is no system.err ! Of course the log call at line 2 says the same.

Comment: what do you think `propStream.toString()` does? (hint: a quick debugging would tell you)

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna use the **getResourceAsStream()** then you have to put the file on the "**src**" folder, together with your *.java* files.

This is usually the way for standard Java applications, but on Android the most usual way to perform such things is to put the file in the 'assets' folder, via [AssetsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html), which is accessible from your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or any [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). like shown below:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   is = context.getAssets().open("data.properties");
} catch (final IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   closeStreamGracefully(is);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getRessourceAsStream return an InputStream. When you call toString on this it will return a  [string representation of the object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). Then when you create your data file and try to read it will try to open a file like @sdqzeffdfsf. If you whant to read the properties from this file use [Properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html)

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(propStream);
```

This is for standard java. However in android you usualy use [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)